# Changing image of a menu button in a CMFCToolbar

Tags: c++, mfc, mfc-feature-pack

I have a menu button inside a `CMFCToolbar` and I would like to replace the bitmap of the button each time a different entry is selected in the menu as each entry has its own icon.

I succeed in changing the icon using `CMFCToolBarMenuButton::SetImage` but it changes the icon in the menu entry too. Too bad.

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/137269b0f2.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/137269b0f2.jpg)     [alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/879d03843a.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/879d03843a.jpg)

Here is a sample of code:

```
if ( (pToolbar != NULL) && (idBase != 0) )
{
    int ixButtonToReplace                   = pToolbar->CommandToIndex(idBase);
    CMFCToolBarMenuButton* pBtnToReplace    = dynamic_cast<CMFCToolBarMenuButton*>
                                                (pToolbar->GetButton(ixButtonToReplace));
    if ( pBtnToReplace )
    {
        const CObList& listCommands = pBtnToReplace->GetCommands();
        POSITION pos                = listCommands.GetHeadPosition();
        while ( pos != NULL )
        {
            CMFCToolBarMenuButton* pItem = (CMFCToolBarMenuButton*) listCommands.GetNext(pos);
            if ( pItem && (pItem->m_nID == idButtonToReplaceWith) )
            {
                pBtnToReplace->SetImage(pItem->GetImage());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: Is the sequence: 12/Content is selected; click on dropdown; click on (X)/Name; Content's icon now changes to Name's?

Answer (score 2):

It works out-of-box. The only you need is to call `CMFCToolBar::AddToolBarForImageCollection` so MFC could know which images to use.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean by the menu button is changed too?

If another button is changed with the single setImage call to the obvious indication is they share a resource ID of some sort, the only solution would be to ensure they have different ID's (which would require making sure both resources are handled separately).
But it's a long time since I messed in MFC resource files to confirm this.